# Best way to select a descendant element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, find

Is there any difference between:

```
var a = $('.a');
$('.b', a).click(function(){

});
```

and:

```
a.find('.b').click(function(){

});
```

?

Comment: "always use find()" they said...

Comment: I remember I saw a post on SO with the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16423239/283863

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) that takes *context* is converted to second one which calls `find` by the jQuery.  I would prefer second one.

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ), [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

Comment: Here the revelant code : https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L199