# What does 'true' mean in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript

This seems like such a basic question, but I swear I can't see it in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

I've inherited some code that does:

```
 $('.tag', true);
```

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) simply say:

> jQuery( selector [, context ] )

And 'true' isn't a context in this case. Is this something to do with bubbling? What does 'true' do in a selector, and where does the documentation cover this use case?

Edit: As A. Wolff notes below, this isn't jQuery, it's an alias for document.querySelector & querySelectorAll.

```
function $(selector, all) {
    return base['querySelector'+(all?'All':'')](selector);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the person writing that code never actually looked at the docs like you did and just put in `true`. Do you observe any effects?

Comment: When I test this, I get back no results, because `true` is actually being used a context, and obviously it doesn't make any sense for `true` to have any DOM elements whatsoever.

Comment: What version of jquery is it? Is/was it built using an old version? Do you get any errors in the console? That selector looks incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure `$` refers to jQuery? Provide more context regarding your posted code. How is it used? Etc...

Comment: $('.tag', false) and $('.tag') returns the same,while true returns nothing

Comment: @Jayababu That's because all falsey context arguments are treated as "use the default context". (`false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`). A missing argument is the same as `undefined`, and for this argument, jQuery treats all falsey values the same.

Comment: `true` is cannot be considered a "context" so it would simply be ignored. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L87

Comment: Here is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector

Comment: @A.Wolff **You're correct - it's a custom function and not jQuery**. If you add this an an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @mikemaccana, do you mean to tell me they intentionally mixed custom code(aliased with $) and jQuery? Ahhhhhhhhhhhh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `$` isn't referring to jQuery but to custom method. Then the `true` parameter has nothing to do with context. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a significant  difference.

Passing `true` forces the context of the returned jQuery object to be `undefined`.

`$('.tag')`, `$('.tag', false)`, `$('.tag', 'body')` etc will all set the context to be `document`, the default.

I dont know why the original programmer have had this need for working on elements with no context, and do not dare to guess.

check it out -> [**`console.dir($('.tag', true));`**](http://jsfiddle.net/zhcLwz3s/)