# Updating a character limit count on my textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I've created my textarea here:

```
textarea {
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(#E0E0E0, .50), 0 -1px 1px #FFF, 0 1px 0 #FFF;

    @include transition(all .2s ease-in-out);

    @include placeholder {
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    }
}
textarea:focus {
    border: 1px solid lighten(#3498db, 10);

    @include box-shadow(0px, 0px, 6px, rgba(lighten(#3498db, 10), .5), false);
}
.textarea-group {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 90px;

    textarea[limit] {
        display: block;
        resize: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .chars {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        background: #FAFAFA;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 11px;
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    }
}
```

And I've written a script to detect changes in my code, however it is not updating my counter. Can anyone tell me why? I think it may be due to the selection of the elements.

```
$(function() {
    $('.textarea-group > textarea[limit]').keyup(function() {
        var max = $(this).attr('limit');
        var length = $(this).val().length;
        length = max - length;
        $(this + ' > .chars span').text(length);
    });
});
```

The script definitely gets called.

**N.B.** I want this to apply to all elements individually that have the same name :)

Thanks!

**EDIT** The final code for jquery is shown below:

```
$(function() {
    $('.textarea-group > textarea[limit]').keyup(function() {
        var max = parseInt($(this).attr('limit'));
        var length = $(this).val().length;
        length = max - length;
        $('.chars span', $(this).parent()).html(length);
    });
});
```

Credits to Francisco (answer) and Akshay (integer parse)

Comment: Try `var max = parseInt($(this).attr('limit'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not a string, so this should fail:

```
$(this + ' > .chars span')
```

In adition, `this` should be the gextarea, so first you have to travel one level up the DOM.

Instead, try using the [second parameter context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector):

```
$('.chars span', this.parentNode)
```

Or use `parent` and `find`:

```
$(this).parent().find('.chars span')
```

Comment: Actually something should be wrong, as you cannot have children of `textarea` as you do in your js

Comment: Ahhh how do I go back in the selector?

Comment: `.parent()` on jQuery is one way, updated. Or `.parentNode` on `this`