# Forcing jQuery to limit its scope to some div

Tags: jquery, scope

Is there a way to replace `$` with something like `$_sub` whose actions are contained within a `div`? For example, I want to inject `$_sub` to a function and instead of using `$`, the function uses `$_sub` to limit its scope within the `div` while preserving the methods that can be called on `$` (e.g I should be able to do `$_sub.ajax()`)

```
<a href="#">Outside </a>
<div id="contents" >
    <a href="#">Inside </a>
</div>

function modify($_sub) {
    var inner_a = $_sub("a"); //should return only the inner <a>
}
```

`context` will not work for me in this scenario. I want the function to think `$_sub` is just like `$`. I can change the function signature to rename `$_sub` to `$` so that the function doesn't even know that it is using a scope limited version of actual `$`.

Comment: design such a way to limit scoping with selector, instead of jquery, because, it loads and works on entire DOM not on specific node in DOM tree.

Comment: Just pass a context in as second parameter ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector

Comment: `$_sub = $` wil copy the jquery reference to the new variable. but its scope won't be just linited to what dom elemetns it can access. Why don't you limit the scope in the parent bases in yur selector? what are yu trying to accomplish

Comment: You could use a more specific selector. EG: `$_sub("#contents a")` which will grab any `a` elements inside the `#contents` element.

Comment: Why not? `var $_sub=$('#contents'); $_sub.find('a');`

Comment: The reason is I want $_sub to behave similar to what $ is doing without the function being aware that it's scope is limited to the div. I might as well rename $_sub to $ in the function signature, so that the function doesn't even know it got modified.

Comment: *"I want $_sub to behave similar to what $ is doing without the function being aware that it's scope is limited to the div."* ~ Can you please explain why you'd need this?

Comment: Let's say the div represents a widget of some sorts. And the javascript should not modify any other elements on the page. One way is to inject $ to the widget function so that modifications are contained within the widget div.

Answer (score 3):

Use  [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context): `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`

Just pass the second parameter.

In your example it would be:
`var inner_a = $("a", "#contents")` which is equivalent to `$("#contents").find("a")`

[What is "context" in jQuery selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector)

Comment: context will not work for me in this scenario. I want the function to think $_sub is just like $. I can change the function signature to rename $_sub to $ so that the function doesn't even know that it is using a scope limited version of actual $

Answer (score 0):

The context option mentioned in other answers seems more sane, but if you really can't use it you could instead curry a function to provide the context automatically, then pass the curried function into your modify function:

```js
var curry = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var fn   = args[0];
  var after = args.slice(1);

  return function() {
    return fn.apply(this, after.concat(
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  };
};    

var _$_sub = function(context, sel) {
  return $(context).find(sel);
}

var $_sub = curry(_$_sub, '#content');

function modify($$) {
  var inner_a = $$("a");
  console.log(inner_a.text());
}

modify($_sub);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Outside</a>
<div id="content">
  <a href="">Inside</a>
</div>
```

Comment: but the curried function returns a jquery element and not jquery function($). So I don't think you can call methods on $$ that you normally would call on $ (e.g, $$.ajax will not work)