# $('form', currentPanel) Selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am familiar to jQuery selector like  $('form') but I am not able to understand what the selector **$('form', currentPanel)** in the below code mean. Please help.

```js
_onWizardNextClick : function() {
 var currentPanel = this.getActivePanel();
 var form = $('form', currentPanel);
 if (form.length == 1 && form.data('validator') && !form.valid()) {
  return;
 }
}
```

Comment: thats the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422478/what-is-context-in-jquery-selector)...

Comment: [it's context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) and this was easy to find on google despite i've never seen it either

Comment: `$(currentPanel).find("form") == $("form", currentPanel)`

Comment: It says, select `form` AND `currentPanel` elements. `currentPanel` is just and DOM element that `this.getActivePanel()` returns

Comment: @user3284463 no, it says, select `form` elements that are below `currentPanel` in the DOM tree (like 'allChildren' or just `find`).  It looks like you're thinking of the comma selector, like this: $(".panel, form") which would select all `.panel` and all `form` elements.  That's not the case here.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Thanks.

Comment: @freedomn-m and codechimp Thanks, I just learnt something new :)