# Hide all li in list but not that li who has class name "matter" using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one list, so I when I click on the button it should hide all li but not that li who has class name "matter" so how to do this using jquery by using only the class name.

```
<ul class="sub-menu">        
  <li >list 1</li>
  <li class="matter">list 2</li>
  <li >list 3</li>
  <li >list 4</li>
</ul>
<button name="btn" class="btn_click">Click me</button>
$(".btn_click").on('click', function() { 

// here code that will hide all li but not that li who has class name 'matter'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the jQuery selector **[`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**, or the jQuery method **[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** like :

```
$('.sub-menu li:not(.matter)').hide();
//Or
$('.sub-menu li').not('.matter').hide();
```

```js
$(".btn_click").on('click', function() {
  $('.sub-menu li:not(.matter)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li class="matter">list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
</ul>

<button name="btn" class="btn_click">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple concept.  Get a reference to all the `li` `$(".sub-menu").find('li')` then exclude the one `.not(".matter")` you do not need and hide the rest.

```js
$(".btn_click").on('click', function() {
  $(".sub-menu").find('li').not(".matter").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li class="matter">list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
</ul>
<button name="btn" class="btn_click">Click me</button>
```

As for why I choose to not use `:not()` here, I just find this easier to read and maintain.

As for the `$(".sub-menu").find('li')` choice https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423239/125981

Alternative use the `.filter()`

```
$(".sub-menu").find('li').filter(":not(.matter)").hide();
```