# Get all elements that contain a particular descendant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through all `<li>` tags that contain the class `.fas` using the jQuery contains() method and perform some stuff on each one.

```
$('li:contains(".fas")').each(function (index) {
    //stuff
}
```

I keep getting the reference error that contains is not defined. Am I using this method incorrectly?

Comment: Wouldn't that loop through all `.fas` that have a parent of `<li>` ? I am trying to get the `<li`>`'s themselves

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, but the query above returns all the `li`s that have class `fas`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I am trying to get all `li`s that have a descedant with a class of `.fas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `has()`.

```
$('li:has(".fas")').each(function (index) {
    //stuff
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: For reference, [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) checks whether a "DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element"; [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selects "all elements that contain the specified text"; [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) reduces "the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element."

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to flip your logic.

```
$('.fas').closest('li');
```

You could find all the fas and then find their parent lis.

Comment: This would run the function for every case where `.fas` is a child of `li`, which would possibly result in repeated execution. where a list item has multiple such child elements.

Comment: That's a true statement

Answer (score -1):

Your question ambiguity leaves me to cross answer this.

First off:

```
$('li.fas')
```

That says to the sizzle engine: Get all elements that have class `fas`, then reduce that to elements of `li` (that have that class)

With a space in between this says:

```
$('li .fas')
```

Get all elements that have a class `fas`, then reduce to those that are a decedent of an `li` element.

```
$('li>.fas')
```

Get all elements that have class `fas`, then reduce that do a set that are direct children of an `li` element.

The other answer has the `.has()` so I will not repeat that.

Filter: (basically same as :has() in this case

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    // reduce the li set; return true when a descendant has the 'fas' class
    return !!$(this).find('.fas').length;
});
```

More on context here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423239/125981

Comment: None of these work for `li`s that contain a descendant with a class of `.fas`

Comment: @noclist Note I added the filter - due to the ambiguity of the question