# How to empty a value from the first option of a select box option using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code. Is it possible to empty the value of the first option using jquery/javascript ?

```
<select id="select_1" name="select_1" class="category-select required">
<option value="0">Select category</option>
<option value="1">Phones</option>
<option value="2">Computers</option>
<option value="3">Tablets</option>
</select>
```

so it will become like that:

```
<option value="">Select category</option>
```

I already know that i can remove the whole first option by targeting its value

```
$("#select_1 option[value='0']").remove();
```

Comment: Did you just make this so you could answer your own question?

Comment: No i will remove my answer cause it solves partially the problem. Check below...I will add a comment.

Comment: Based on your question, I would think your provided answer would accomplish what you want, what is wrong with the answer your provided?

Comment: The problem is that my code will empty the value if is equal to zero (value="0"). What i want is to empty the value of the very first option no matter if the value is 0 or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plain javascript to get the first option of a select element using `.options` like so, which returns an indexed collection, so you can just use zero based index to grab the first option and set it's value property:

```
document.getElementById("select_1").options[0].value = '';
```

Comment: @Designer I believe Rory was first to answer, so he is deserving of the points for the accepted answer, but if you want to use plain javascript instead of relying on a JQuery library, this answer would provide what you need.

Answer (score 2):

To target the first element of a collection use `:first`. Then you can use `val('')` to remove the `value` from it:

```js
$('#select_1 option:first').val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1" name="select_1" class="category-select required">
<option value="0">Select category</option>
<option value="1">Phones</option>
<option value="2">Computers</option>
<option value="3">Tablets</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OR `$('#select_1').find('option').first().val('');` which I prefer due to the right to left processing of the sizzle engine jQuery uses.

Comment: Shouldn't be `$('#select_1').find('option').first().val('');`     ?

Comment: more details on "context" and my comment, but yes either one will work and only on a very large DOM or micro optimized page is there relevance https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423239/125981  ( or really old browsers where is shows up more )

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){

 $('#btnremoveoption').click(function (){
   $('#select_1 option:first').remove();
 });

});

</script>
<body>
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1" class="category-select required">
      <option value="0">Select category</option>
      <option value="1">Phones</option>
      <option value="2">Computers</option>
      <option value="3">Tablets</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" id="btnremoveoption" value="Click to Remove all Options" onclick="Remove_options()"/>
</body>
```

This Program will keep Removing first option when ever button will be click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){


   $('#select_1 option:first').remove();


});
```

this will remove it onload of the page. without leaving the option blank it will be filled with the next option.