# Multiple Selector like statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know what a multiple selector does

```
$( "p , #test" )
```

It gives the combined results of all the specified selectors and I can find some documentation for it.

But I found this piece of syntax somewhere and I dont know how its called and cant find a way to explain it. Can anyone tell me the name and where I can find some documentaion

```
$( "p" , "#test" )
```

it seems to get all p elements only within the element with id=test

Comment: similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092500/comma-separated-list-of-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` selector's second parameter is the context.

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context. Accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements.

Have a look at the [**Docs**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

Answer (score 3):

This selector is called [`context selector`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

> Accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements.

[**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)