# How do I return an entire div inside of a div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am looping through all the grocery_items and getting its attributes. But why is the grocery item label not returning the 
entire div inside i.e:

```
<div class="column-right feedcontainer" id="protein"></div> 
<div class="column-left feedcontainer" id="sodium"></div>?
```

Here is my code, HTML

```
 <div class="grocery_items" data-gs-height="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-x=
"10" data-gs-y="6">
    <div class="grocery_item_label">
        <div class="column-left feedcontainer" id="sodium"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grocery_items" data-gs-height="4" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-x=
"10" data-gs-y="6">
    <div class="grocery_item_label">
        <div class="column-right feedcontainer" id="protein"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){ 
var items =[];
$('.grocery_items').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    items.push({
        x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
        y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
        w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
        h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),


        content: $('.grocery-item_label', $this).html()

    });
   });

     alert(JSON.stringify(items));
      });
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xu0ck30h/4/.
Output is something like this:

```
[{"x":"0","y":"12","w":"4","h":"4","content":"  <div id=\”Protein\" class=\"column-center feedcontainer\"></div>\n"},{"x":"4","y":"12","w":"4","h":"4","content":"  <div id=\”Sodium\" class=\"column-left feedcontainer\"></div>\n"},
```

Comment: What is your intended output supposed to be? What do you expect?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja The output should be like that on the last line. But I can't seem to get it working. I know my attr are right

Comment: It's not working because you've misspelt your selector with a `-` instead of a `_`. It reads `.grocery-item_label` but should be  `.grocery_item_label`. http://jsfiddle.net/s99x17nh/ works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `$($this).find('.grocery_item_label').html()` instead.

```
$(function () {
    var items = [];
    $('.grocery_items').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        items.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $($this).find('.grocery_item_label').html()
        });
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
});
```

The selector `$('.grocery-item_label', $this)` is sort of unclear; you're basically telling jQuery "Select each element with the class `.grocery-item_label`, and this one too.".

`$($this).find('.grocery_item_label').html()` will select the `.grocery-item_label` which is being iterated over, and then try to find the child element with the class `grocery_item_label`.  On a side note, if there are multiple children, using `.first()` will help you find the first child element.

Also, there's a typo in your code: `$('.grocery-item_label')` shouldn't return any results.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n3ecwym/).

Comment: What's the issue?  I'm getting `[{"x":"10","y":"6","w":"4","h":"4","content":"\n        <div class=\"column-left feedcontainer\" id=\"sodium\"></div>\n    "},  "x":"10","y":"6","w":"4","h":"4","content":"\n        <div class=\"column-right feedcontainer\" id=\"protein\"></div>\n    "}]` in the console.

Comment: @JohnLen Maybe try using `$().html().trim()`?  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Thanks for all your replies @alex but it's not a whitespace problem.

Comment: 1. There's nothing wrong with op's selector, `$('.grocery-item_label', $this)` tells jquery to look for `.grocery-item_label` inside of `$this`. The only problem is the misspelling. 2. In your code `$($this)` is superfluous, it already is a jquery object. Just `$this` would work just fine.

Comment: @Jan +1, [fair enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092500/comma-separated-list-of-selectors).  The OP's code is, I believe, functionally identical to my approach using `.find()`. But in my defense, the OP is using `var $this = $this`, which is superfluous.

Comment: OP used `var $this = $(this);`, it's not really superfluous since storing the jquery object in a variable you only have to do the jquery conversion once.

Comment: @alex THANK YOU the trim idea did not work. However it gave me the idea to remove the extra tags around and it now works. You're my hero :) I have been stuck for a day on how to approach it.