# Comma Separated selector in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I came across the following code in JQuery which I'm not familiar with

```
$('*[name=\'' + child.Name + '\'],[id=\'' + child.ID + '\']');
```

I have two different divs(different IDs) containing two input elements with same name. When I pass the name and ID to the above query, I get both the input elements.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092500/comma-separated-list-of-selectors) on Stack Overflow, but if what is mentioned there is correct, I should be getting the element with in the div which I pass.

I want to know how this would work:

```
$('[name=""],[id=""]');
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just google bro , https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: for id you can use `#`

Comment: If you have a problem selecting, provide a snippet with which we can reproduce it.

Comment: The question you linked to is about `$("selector1", "selector2")`, not `$("selector1, selector2")`. Notice the difference in the number of arguments.

Comment: @Barmar I found the difference. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the jQuery documentation on [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

> **Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)**
>   **Description**: Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

The other question you linked to is about the syntax:

```
$("selector1", "selector2")
```

That's an example of the `jQuery(selector, context)` syntax described [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), which is equivalent to `jQuery(context).find(selector)`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I can't change the code as it is from the production library. I just wanted to know what "," does in the selector.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking how to get the second effect. I've rewritten my answer to more directly address your actual question.